# Transformations of random variables that aren't one-to-one

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

In a mathematical model I've written, values for one of the parameters  (call this parameter $b$) are sampled uniformly from trial to trial from a Gabor function.

The Gabor function $G$ is as follows:

\begin{align}
b_x = G(x) =h e^{-(wx)^2}\sin(wx).
\end{align}

Here, $x$ is an independent variable selected from a uniform distribution from trial to trial.  $h$ and $w$ are fixed.

My question is, what is the PDF for my parameter $b$?

Note that the Gabor function integrates to 0 across its domain (which is $-\pi$ to $\pi$).  It is not one-to-one.

Comment: Hint: You know the distribution of a random variable $X$, and want the distribution of $B:= G(X)$. The standard results on transformations of random variables apply, irrespective of the integral of $G$. See section 2 in [this pdf](http://math.arizona.edu/~jwatkins/f-transform.pdf), for instance.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 many thanks.  but wait.  the article you sent only explains how to compute the PDF i want for the case that $G$ is one-to-one.  my Gabor function isn't one-to-one.  right?

Comment: @stochasticboy321 should i break up the function into the sub-domains over which it is one-to-one?

Comment: @dbliss If $g$ is a piecewise monotone measurable function and $X$ a continuous random variable then $g(X)$ is a continuous random variable and indeed that would be the simples way to compute the distribution of $g(X)$.

Comment: @Math1000 $g$ is right there in my question.  it's the Gabor function.  it is piecewise monotonic, but getting an analytical expression for the inverse of each piece is by no means a simple strategy.  i've given up on expressing the PDF i'm looking for analytically and am now numerically approximating it using a Monte Carlo simulation.